# How to dynamic handle roles|permissions in Symfony2 at database level: CRUD operations over them

Tags: php, symfony, security, acl

I am working in a Symfony 2.8 project and I have a doubt regarding users/groups/roles|permissions. There are a few ways to handle users and groups as for example [SonataUser](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle) on top of [SonataAdmin](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle) and lately [EasyAdmin](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) but all of them lacks ROLE|permissions management and this is exactly my doubt: what's the proper way to handle them? Yes, I know I need to write them at `security.yml` but I don't know if I can store then in DB (somewhere) and then read from there. I have research about this and found ACL, Voters and so on but instead of clear my mind the research is confusing me a lot so I need some push from people here. Then:

- How would you handle this?
- Any example at code level? (I prefer to see something other than words to get the whole point)
- Are ROLES sames as permissions?

**Update: improve question**

What I want to have is a `ManyToMany` relationship between `users` and `roles` and possibly `groups` and `roles`. I think that as `SonataUserBundle` handle this is by creating a column `roles` in `user` table and assign a lot of roles to each user, even create new ones if I'm not mistaken but what about if I want to create as much roles as I can without assign them to a user and later add many roles to a user even to a group?

How would you do that?

Comment: Have you looked into [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)? It stores the roles in the database and you can add a role dynamically.

Comment: @DipenShah yes, they store roles in database (`roles` column at user table) but those roles needs to be created by hand first because they read them from `security.yml` perhaps I am wrong but this is what I think is happening behind scenes

Comment: Nope you can add new roles on the go. There is no need to add it in the `security.yml` file

Comment: @DipenShah can you show me how? I mean do you have any code related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new roles in the `FOSUserBundle` on the go. There is no need for you to initially add it in the `security.yml` file.

To do this you can do something like this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->addRole('ROLE_NEWUSER'); //Role Name should begin with 'ROLE_'
```

or in your controller you can get current or any user

```
$this->getUser();
$user->addRole('ROLE_NEWUSER'); //Role Name should begin with 'ROLE_'
```

This answers your first and second part.

For the third part, Roles *can* be used as permissions. I have implemented a structure previously where I was restricting access to pages based on the user role also restricting what data they can change based on their role.

**UPDATE** I implemented an [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html) for this which would listen to all the kernel requests which is called `onKernelRequest`. I have partially done the access management on the SQL side since I have my roles stored in SQL side as well but one can do the same on the Server side. My Event Listener looked like this: (This is a trimmed down version of what I have)

```
class TokenListener
{
    protected $em;
    protected $token_storage;
    protected $templating;
    protected $router;
    protected $resolver;
    public function __construct($em,TokenStorageInterface $token_storage, TwigEngine $templating, Router $router, ControllerResolver $resolver)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
    }


    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');
        $routeArr = array('fos_js_routing_js', 'fos_user_security_login', '_wdt'); //These are excluded routes. These are always allowed. Required for login page
        if(!is_int(array_search($route, $routeArr)) && false)
        {
            $userRoles = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles();
            if(!in_array('ROLE_NEWUSER', $userRoles))
            {
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_management_unauthorized_user', array())));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My services.yml looks like this

```
services:
    app.tokens.action_listener:
        class: EventListenerBundle\EventListener\TokenListener
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            token_storage: "@security.token_storage"
            templating: "@templating"
            router: "@router"
            resolver: "@controller_resolver"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

**UPDATE** To answer your update part of the question, what you can do is have another `roles` entity and you could populate the roles you want in advance and then have a one to many relationship with the original `User` table. You can then have something like [`prePersist or preUpdate Doctrine Lifecycle Events`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) to check when adding a new if the role already exists in your roles entity. That should precisely solve your problem. All this will involve a little tweaking though. There is no straight way to do this.

Comment: Okey, take a look to the OP, I have changed things a few since I am not building my own user management system instead I am using SonataUserBundle one, perhaps I should start from there for avoid confusions

Comment: I am not sure about `SonataUserBundle` This was a solution for `FOSUserBundle` as I explained before. This is not my own system just an `eventListener` on top of everything.

Comment: Ok, even if your answer help me to see beyond I will wait a few until accept your question, if you have any other idea please share with me. I hope someone from Sonata side could help me

Comment: Look [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/introduction.html) The first line says it Integrates the `FOS/UserBundle` in the `Sonata Admin Project` and adds some features. So it is basically `FOSUserBundle` with some features on top of it. I am pretty sure you can implement my concept on Sonata User Bundle as well since it builds on top of `FOSUserBundle`

Comment: did your `TokenListener` answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215854/how-to-dynamic-handle-rolespermissions-in-symfony2-restrict-functions-with-dyn) in somehow? Can you take a look to the new post?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to implement this.

One approach:

Implement the `UserProviderInterface` to `loadByUsername` (this is where you load the roles and permissions) an implementation of a `UserInterface` (your `User`).

Then Implement the `VoterInterface`. Register this as a service tagged with `security.voter` and specify it as a provider in security.yml. Override the `vote` function to assess the `User` you loaded for permissions (and maybe roles too) from `TokenInterface` which is the first argument of that function.

Comment: Okey, same question as for @dipen-shah any code to show this? I mean a little example I just need a start point something to dig on not just words ;)

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user In order to get hold your permissions, you **can** implement your own User