# How to dynamic handle roles|permissions in Symfony2: restrict functions with dynamic roles

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, authorization

This post aims to be a kind of second part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184630/how-to-dynamic-handle-rolespermissions-in-symfony2-at-database-level-crud-oper/) post so you may have to read it to understand this question. Having that info and the answer from previous post and also having found [this](https://github.com/juanmf/UserBundle) useful **UserBundle** which help me as an example to illustrate possible relationship as `Many To Many` between `roles` and `users` I may ask:

- I have dynamic roles and now how I use those new `ROLES`?

What I mean, for example I want to limit a existent function to role `ROLE_NEWROLE` which has been created dynamically and therefore doesn't exists on the base code (original sources) then how do I restrict a existent function to that new role? Take the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html#usage) as an example:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The code above presume that `ROLE_ADMIN` is already declared somewhere and somehow but what if I want to add the new `ROLE_NEWROLE` to that function through security component? Do I need to touch my code all the time? That isn't funny at all so I want to know your opinions about this topic.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question clearly. What existent function are you talking about here? It is not clear to me what do you exactly wanna do. Could you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: Also I don't see any documentation for this bundle that you have mentioned. What extra features does this bundle add over the original FOS/UserBundle?

Comment: @DipenShah for your first doubt take a look to the OP I have made some improves, I am referring to `Security` component. For the second one that Bundle offers nothing just a way to see how to manage `roles` independent from `users` and a possible way to join them

Comment: This is exactly what the event listener was for in my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34185226/4841794). It does exactly the same job that you want to do. A better option that I can give you is that to store all your routes and the roles that you want to let it access it to in the database itself. This was exactly my requirement some time ago and its successfully working for me right now.

Comment: @DipenShah I know almost all the time code is private but can you share this small part of your code to see how it works? I don't need an entire project just the classes related to this and security and so on, everything you know will be interesting for follow your approach. Sorry for my poor knowledge

Comment: I will post an answer in some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked about this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34185226/4841794), you need to implement `EventListener` which will listen to your `onKernelRequest`.

In plain English, this means that **all** of your Controller Actions will execute `onKernelRequest` first before giving access to the original controller. So this way you won't have to write

```
/**
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
```

in every controller action.

Now, its upto you what you want to do in this method. My approach was to make a table which associates a `ROLE` with a `ROUTE`. This table will be comparatively big because you have to include all `ROLES` you want to give access to all `ROUTES`.

The table structure can be something like this:

```
ACCESSID      ROLENAME                ROUTENAME
    1       ROLE_NEWUSER       contacts_lookup_homepage
    2       ROLE_SUPER_USER    contacts_lookup_homepage
```

According to this table only `ROLE_NEWUSER` and `ROLE_SUPER_USER` are eligible to access the route `contacts_lookup_homepage`

This way now only those roles are allowed to access `contacts_lookup_homepage` route. Now on the `onKernelRequest` all you will do is query this table and check if there is a match with that role with that route. You have access to both in this method. These routes are the same as the one you define in your `routing.yml` file of every route. If you're not sure, it looks something like this:

```
contacts_lookup_homepage:
    path:     /Contacts/Lookup
    defaults: { _controller: ContactsLookupBundle:Default:index }
```

Now finally in your `onKernelRequest` you can do something like this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route  = $request->attributes->get('_route');
    $routeArr = array('fos_js_routing_js', 'fos_user_security_login', '_wdt'); //These are excluded routes. These are always allowed. Required for login page
    $roleArr = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getRoles();

    if(!is_int(array_search($route, $routeArr))) //This is for excluding routes that you don't want to check for.
    {
        //Check for a matching role and route
        $qb = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserAccess')->createQueryBuilder('o');
        $qb
            ->select('o')
            ->where('o.ROLENAME IN (:roleArr)')
            ->setParameter('roleArr', $roleArr)
            ->andWhere('o.ROUTENAME = :route')
            ->setParameter('route', $route)
        ;
        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
        if(empty($result))
        {
            //A matching role and route was not found so we do not give access to the user here and redirect to another page.
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_management_unauthorized_user', array())));
        }
    }
}
```

The `services.yml` can be like this:

```
services:
    app.tokens.action_listener:
        class: EventListenerBundle\EventListener\TokenListener
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            token_storage: "@security.token_storage"
            templating: "@templating"
            router: "@router"
            resolver: "@controller_resolver"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

This will guarantee that no unauthorized user accesses the controller action which is not authorized. I hope that gives you an idea about the implementation.

Comment: It does, thanks, I will comeback here if anything comes up on the coding but for now I get the idea behind your explanation