# How to create a DMZ using Symfony/FOSUser?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

We have an application built in Symfony (CMF) and using the FOSUser bundle. We have the requirement to implement a "DMZ" for certain users who have not completed certain tasks (e.g. legacy users who have not signed up for the latest terms and conditions). We need to validate these users before they are allowed to complete the tasks (e.g. login before we can work out which Ts and Cs to show them) but they must not be allowed to access the rest of their account until they have completed the task (e.g. agreed to the relevant terms and conditions). For clarification, there may be multiple tasks a user might need to complete (e.g. agreeing to different Ts & Cs for different products) and they should only gain full access once all tasks are complete.

We are currently doing this by creating two roles for each account; one for the "basic" account and one for an account which has completed all the relevant steps. This means adding (or removing) one of the roles on a successful login and doesn't feel like the best way to handle this situation as these are not really "roles" in the traditional sense.

One specific problem we have encountered (we are currently adding the full role on login as appropriate) is that we cannot impersonate these users as the impersonation mechanics loads the user from the database and the full role is only granted on successful login and does not exist in the database.

Is there a recognised or canonical Symfony way of achieving this? I've tried search engines, the Symfony docs and SO but can't see any sort of discussion about this sort of thing.

Comment: What about implementing a voter that performs this check (whether or not this a good idea depends on how expensive it is to check the needed permissions)?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184630/how-to-dynamic-handle-rolespermissions-in-symfony2-at-database-level-crud-oper/34185226#34185226) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215854/how-to-dynamic-handle-rolespermissions-in-symfony2-restrict-functions-with-dyn/34226319#34226319) Your problems are relatively similar to what the OP had. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @xabbuh Thanks for the suggestion although I'm not sure it adds anything to what we are already doing (we are using the login success handler to check the relevant tasks and issue roles accordingly).

Comment: @DipenShah I don't really see that solution is any different to the one we are currently implementing (we are already dynamically adding or removing a role on login).

Answer (score 1):

@liquorvicar I think that security voters are the right way to go as xabbuh says. The advantage is the you do not need to add/remove roles which in turn should solve your impersonation issues. The voter/logic denies access not the role.
Further reading: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html#how-to-use-the-voter-in-a-controller and http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html

Comment: so how would you go about implementing it? Have a basic role for any account no matter how "complete" and then implement a voter to restrict any pages you need restricted manually? Does that get run on every request then? What would we use as the subject of the voter? The user itself?

Comment: "Have a basic role for any account no matter how "complete" and then implement a voter to restrict any pages you need restricted manually?" Yes -- "Does that get run on every request then?" Yes, you need to keep this lean, cache what you can against the user. -- "What would we use as the subject of the voter? The user itself?" Yes